# Mockito: mocking an arraylist that will be looped in a for loop

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a method under test that contains the following snippet:

```
private void buildChainCode(List<TracedPath> lines){
    for(TracedPath path : lines){
        /.../
    }
}
```

My unit test code looks like this:

```
public class ChainCodeUnitTest extends TestCase {

    private @Mock List<TracedPath> listOfPaths;
    private @Mock TracedPath tracedPath;

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    public void testGetCode() {
        when(listOfPaths.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(tracedPath);

        ChainCode cc = new ChainCode();
        cc.getCode(listOfPaths);

        /.../
    }
}
```

The problem is, that while running the test, the test code never enters the for loop. What when conditions should I specify, so that the for loop would be entered? Currently I have specified `when(listOfPaths.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(tracedPath)`, but I guess it is never used.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Your problem is that when you use a collection in a for-each loop, its `iterator()` method gets called; and you haven't stubbed that particular method.

Instead of mocking the list, I strongly recommend you just pass a real list, where the elements are just your mocked `TracedPath`, as many times as you want it.  Something like

```
listOfPaths = Arrays.asList(mockTracedPath, mockTracedPath, mockTracedPath);
```

Comment: what if you do not know the elements that will be added to the list?

Comment: You choose the elements, depending on what you're trying to test.

Comment: The listOfPaths must be then set explicit to the class under test and can't be annotated with @Mock.

Comment: what if the list is supposed to be empty?

Comment: @Shilan then just use an empty list!

Comment: If list needs to be empty then just new ArrayList()

Comment: @Cengiz what can be done if the list is autowired using spring framework and there is no setter in the class?

Comment: @user3153014 Create setter and if that is not possible use reflection.

Answer (score 7):

The Java For-Each loop used inside your `buildChainCode` method isn't calling `get()`, as you already figured out - it's using the `iterator()` method defined in `Collection<E>`, which `List<E>` extends.

I *really* wouldn't recommend mocking the list. There's no advantage to it, unless you absolutely must check that the list was iterated through, and even then, it's better to assert on or verify the results of your class's behaviour given certain inputs.

Pass some implementation of `List<E>` like `LinkedList<E>` with `tracedPath` in it.

Comment: Thank you for a good explanation. I would mark it as an answer but a very similar one was submitted just 3 minutes before yours.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I got called away to fix something before I could finish my post - c'est la vie :) David's is a good answer.