# Create a mocked list by mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I want to create a mocked list to test below code:

```
 for (String history : list) {
        //code here
    }
```

Here is my implementation:

```
public static List<String> createList(List<String> mockedList) {

    List<String> list = mock(List.class);
    Iterator<String> iterHistory = mock(Iterator.class);

    OngoingStubbing<Boolean> osBoolean = when(iterHistory.hasNext());
    OngoingStubbing<String> osHistory = when(iterHistory.next());

    for (String history : mockedList) {

        osBoolean = osBoolean.thenReturn(true);
        osHistory = osHistory.thenReturn(history);
    }
    osBoolean = osBoolean.thenReturn(false);

    when(list.iterator()).thenReturn(iterHistory);

    return list;
}
```

But when the test run it throw exception at line:

```
OngoingStubbing<DyActionHistory> osHistory = when(iterHistory.next());
```

for details:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when(PowerMockito.java:495)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
```

How can i fix it ? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mockito: mocking an arraylist that will be looped in a for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483176/mockito-mocking-an-arraylist-that-will-be-looped-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

OK, this is a bad thing to be doing.  Don't mock a list; instead, mock the individual objects inside the list.  See [Mockito: mocking an arraylist that will be looped in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483176/mockito-mocking-an-arraylist-that-will-be-looped-in-a-for-loop) for how to do this.

Also, why are you using PowerMock?  You don't seem to be doing anything that requires PowerMock.

But the real cause of your problem is that you are using `when` on two different objects, before you complete the stubbing.  When you call `when`, and provide the method call that you are trying to stub, then the very next thing you do in either Mockito OR PowerMock is to specify what happens when that method is called - that is, to do the `thenReturn` part.  Each call to `when` must be followed by one and only one call to `thenReturn`, before you do any more calls to `when`.  You made two calls to `when` without calling `thenReturn` - that's your error.

Comment: but if you REALLY had to, how would you mock a list?

Comment: Why would you REALLY have to?  It's invariably the wrong thing to be doing.  This is like asking "what if you REALLY had to use a hammer to drive a screw".  It's the wrong approach - the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: how do you return a normal list then with mocked items inside?

Comment: Look at my answer to the question that I linked to.

Comment: Question: How do I solve X? Answer: Don't do X, do Y instead. I don't get why this is the accepted answer.

Comment: @GabrielOshiro - I'll try to help you understand.  The OP posted some code with an error in it, and asked the question "how can I fix it".  My third paragraph explained their error.  My answer offered a solution to their problem.  So I've actually answered their question completely.  I hope this helps you "get why" this is the accepted answer.

Comment: Summary:  Don't mock a list; instead, mock the individual objects inside the list

Answer (score 14):

When dealing with mocking lists and iterating them, I always use something like:

```
@Spy
private List<Object> parts = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 7):

We can mock list properly for foreach loop. Please find below code snippet and explanation.

This is my actual class method where I want to create test case by mocking list.
`this.nameList` is a list object.

```
public void setOptions(){
    // ....
    for (String str : this.nameList) {
        str = "-"+str;
    }
    // ....
}
```

The foreach loop internally works on iterator, so here we crated mock of iterator.
Mockito framework has facility to return pair of values on particular method call by using `Mockito.when().thenReturn()`, i.e. on `hasNext()` we pass 1st true and on second call false, so that our loop will continue only two times. On `next()` we just return actual return value.

```
@Test
public void testSetOptions(){
    // ...
    Iterator<SampleFilter> itr = Mockito.mock(Iterator.class);
    Mockito.when(itr.hasNext()).thenReturn(true, false);
    Mockito.when(itr.next()).thenReturn(Mockito.any(String.class);  

    List mockNameList = Mockito.mock(List.class);
    Mockito.when(mockNameList.iterator()).thenReturn(itr);
    // ...
}
```

In this way we can avoid sending actual list to test by using mock of list.

Comment: This is not the correct way to use `Mockito.any` - in fact, if you were to stub a method with some arguments, after the third line here, it would fail, because you've added a matcher to Mockito's internal stack, and not used it in a `when`.  Moreover, apart from the bug that you introduced, and the obvious syntax error on the third line; what you've achieved with 5 lines of code is exactly the same as writing `List mockNameList = Collections.singletonList(null);`  Why would you write 5 lines to do something so simple?