# how to mock in Java

Tags: java, mocking

I have the following code

```
list.getnames().get(0).getFirstName();
```

This in the code is dynamic as the `get(0)` is loaded when the data is available. I am writing tests for this in Junit and when I create a mock by doing

```
when(list.getnames().get(0).getFirstName()).thenReturn(null);
```

then, I get the error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

I understand that this is because there is no value at this point and as a result it is 0 in size, but what is the right way to mock the field, so I can create my test?

Comment: You will have to mock the list as well. You can use spy / mock list in order to test this scenario. Also could you please add more information as in what type of test you are writing ? whats there in the list ? type ? etc.

Comment: You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/q/18514033/10553411

Comment: you are mocking the getFirstName() call, but what if the getnames() returns an empty list? that's your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the `List<User>` (`User` is your entity) as below,

```
User user = new User("firstname", "lastname");

List<User> mock = mock(List.class);
when(mock.get(0)).thenReturn(user);

assertEquals("firstname", mock.get(0).getFirstName());
```

Comment: it's best also explaining why this solves his issue, and why this won't meet his requirements.