# Mockito : Testing void methods gives InvalidUseOfMatchersException

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm having problems with two void methods. In `encouragedVenturesScoring` I've followed this answer [mocking an arraylist that will be looped in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483176/mockito-mocking-an-arraylist-that-will-be-looped-in-a-for-loop/) and haven't mocked the list, but passed a real list and added mocked objects.

Mockito gives me an InvalidUseOfMatchersException on this line

`verify(effectList.get(Mockito.anyInt())).execute(playerHandler);`

There are lots of questions on SO on this exception , and I think it's because of anyInt(). Anyway I changed it to

```
verify(effectList.get(0)).execute(playerHandler);
```

And now it's saying `Wanted but not invoked effect.execute(playerHandler)`
`Actually there were zero interactions with this mock`

Is it because I put doNothing ?
`doNothing().when(effect).execute(playerHandler);`

---

In my second method `militaryStrengthScoring()` method is there a way to skip the first chunk of code and just test the if..else condition? What would be the best approach to test this method?

Thank you for your time.

**This is the class to be tested**

```
 public class EndGameScoringBaseController implements EndGameScoringHandler {

private static final int[] TERRITORIES_REWARD = {0,0,1,4,10,20};
private static final int[] CHARACTERS_REWARD = {1,3,6,10,15,21};
private static final int RESOURCES_RATE = 5;
private static final int FIRST_MILITARY_REWARD = 5;
private static final int SECOND_MILITARY_REWARD = 2;

private PlayerHandler player;

public EndGameScoringBaseController(PlayerHandler player) {
    super();
    this.player = player;
}

@Override
public void encouragedVenturesScoring() {
    for (DevelopmentCard card : player.getPlayer().getPersonalBoard().getVentures()) {
        for (Effect e : card.getPermanentEffects())
            e.execute(player);
    }
}

@Override
public void militaryStrengthScoring(GameController game) {
    Set<Integer> points = new HashSet<>();
    int myPoints = this.player.getPointsHandler().getMilitaryPoints();

    for (PlayerHandler p: game.getPlayers()) {
        points.add(p.getPointsHandler().getMilitaryPoints());
    }
    int[] rank = new int[points.size()];
    int j = 0;
    for (Integer i : points) {
        rank[j] = i;
        j++;
    }

    Arrays.sort(rank);

    if (rank[rank.length-1] == myPoints) {
        player.getPointsHandler().winMilitaryPoints(FIRST_MILITARY_REWARD);
    }
    else if (rank[rank.length-2] == myPoints) {
        player.getPointsHandler().winVictoryPoints(SECOND_MILITARY_REWARD);
    }

}
```

**Tested method for encouragedVenturesScoring**

```
@Test
public void encouragedVenturesScoringTest() {
    //given
    List<DevelopmentCard> ventureList;
    ventureList = Arrays.asList(developmentCard, developmentCard);
    when(playerHandler.getPlayer().getPersonalBoard().getVentures()).thenReturn(ventureList);
    List<Effect> effectList;
    effectList = Arrays.asList(effect, effect);
    when(developmentCard.getPermanentEffects()).thenReturn(effectList);
    doNothing().when(effect).execute(playerHandler);

    //when
    endgameController.encouragedVenturesScoring();

    //then
    verify(effectList.get(Mockito.anyInt())).execute(playerHandler);
}
```

**Incomplete tested method for militaryStrengthScoring**

```
@Test
public void militaryStrengthScoringTest() {

//given     
when(playerHandler.getPointsHandler().getMilitaryPoints()).thenReturn(4);
doNothing().when(playerHandler.getPointsHandler()).winMilitaryPoints(FIRST_MILITARY_REWARD);

//when
endgameController.militaryStrengthScoring(gameController);

//then
/../    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that this is the problem:

```
verify(effectList.get(Mockito.anyInt())).execute(playerHandler);
```

Mockito only allows for calls like `any()` and `anyInt()` to stand in for parameters to the mock themselves, due to the [internal implementation of matchers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891).

```
/*  OK */  when(yourMock.yourMethod(anyInt())).thenReturn(42);
/* BAD */  when(yourList.get(anyInt()).yourMethod(0)).thenReturn(42);

/*  OK */  verify(yourMock).yourMethod(anyInt());
/* BAD */  verify(yourList.get(anyInt())).yourMethod(0);
```

The failure with `get(0)` is likely an actual failure, and may be related to the fact that your `encouragedVenturesScoringTest` is actually not calling `encouragedVenturesScoring`, it's calling `influencedCharactersScoring`. If this continues to give you trouble after fixing that error, in ways related to Mockito, please edit your question.

Comment: Thank you! I completely missed I was calling the wrong method. I changed it to `endgameController.encouragedVenturesScoring()` and it's working now. Btw is this the best way to test methods like these?

Comment: @LoSpazzino Glad to help! For the "is this the best way to test",  that could easily be a 20-page rant, so let me just say: I think unit tests are valuable and that this is a good start, but I'm concerned that overuse of mocks will make it really hard to determine whether your system actually works. Yes, you can verify that the call to `execute` succeeds, but I'd guess that your cards and players are relatively self-contained and easy to write (and test in isolation). Using them instead of Mockito simulations may make it easier to reason about whether your system actually works.

Answer (score 1):

You can only verify mock objects created by Mockito.

But *effectList* is a "real" list. Therefore Mockito knows nothing about that object. Thus any attempt to verify that list must fail.

If you want to verify that object - then you have to mock it!

Of course, this means that you have specify all calls that will go to the mocked list.

Comment: I'd also add if you are going into this level of mocking/effort your class is likely too complicated as it stands to effectively unit test and should be refactored asap.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, actually: `verify(effectList.get(0)).execute(playerHandler)` seems to be trying to verify _the Effect in the list, not the list itself_. I prefer not to allow extra method calls in my `when` and `verify` calls, but that's not really a problem.

Comment: I was calling the wrong method and everything is fixed now with: `verify(effectList.get(0), times(4)).execute(playerHandler);
verify(effectList.get(1), times(4)).execute(playerHandler);`. Could you suggest me the best way to refactor my second method `militaryStrengthScoringTest` so it's easier to test ?

Comment: Are you sure that this is really **verifying** anything? The fact that the method doesn't throw an error doesn't mean it is really doing anything. Have you ensured that your test is *failing* when something happens that the verification did not expect?